# 413 Request Entity Too Large in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, form-data

I am using node js express. I am uploadinga pdf and using form data. but when i call api and send the file then i get error as

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

I have the below code to fix this but it didn't work.

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true,limit: '50mb' }));
```

Below is the code for file for `server.ts`.

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
const formData = require('express-form-data');
const os = require('os');
import { BAD_REQUEST } from 'http-status-codes';
import BaseRouter from './routes/index.route';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import logger from './shared/logger';
import cors from 'cors';
import fs from 'fs'
import { FilePath } from './shared/constants';

// creating default directories

const dir = FilePath;
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

// Init express
const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true,limit: '50mb' }));


// For form data
const options = {
    uploadDir: os.tmpdir(),
    autoClean: true
};
// parse data with connect-multiparty.
app.use(formData.parse(options));
// delete from the request all empty files (size == 0)
app.use(formData.format());
// change the file objects to fs.ReadStream
// app.use(formData.stream());
// union the body and the files
// app.use(formData.union());

// Cors
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

app.disable('etag');
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let allowedOrigins: any = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIONS || '*';
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins === '*') {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin as string);
    } else {
        allowedOrigins = allowedOrigins.split(',');
        if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin as string);
        }
    }
    // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIONS); // Will update DOmain later here
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next();
});
// Add APIs
app.use('/', BaseRouter);

app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    logger.error(err.stack || err.message)
    return res.status(BAD_REQUEST).json({
        error: err.message,
    });
});




// Export express instance
export default app;
```

Comment: [Is there a maximum size for content of an HTTP POST?](https://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

Because:

> The parameterLimit option controls the maximum number of parameters
> that are allowed in the URL-encoded data. If a request contains more
> parameters than this value, a 413 will be returned to the client.
> Defaults to 1000.

you can try those options:

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true,limit: '50mb', parameterLimit: 50000 }));
```

Comment: It did not help by adding parameterLimit.Still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set nginx file config to

```
client_max_body_size: 50m;
```

you can find it by access `etc/nginx/sites-enabled`
or wherever you made the host file